# How to plot GEBCO bathymetry data with python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I'm trying to plot bathymetry data(from [GEBCO database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WOTjMYJamBAJ7Qd4-Ivh-RgwdcWfl8yz)). I am trying to plot lat, long and elevation using seaborn python. Data is in the netCDF format. I managed to load data correctly using xarray. 
Here is the code snippet.

```sh
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr

ds = Dataset('gebco_2019.nc')

lats = ds.variables['lat'][:]
lons = ds.variables['lon'][:]
tid = ds.variables['tid'][:]

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(
    contours = {
        "x": {"show": True, "size": 0.04, "color":"white"},
        "z": {"show": True, "size": 0.05}
    },
    x = ds.variables['lat'],
    y = ds.variables['lon'],
    z = [
        ds.variables['tid']
    ]))
fig.show()
```

try to plot 3D plot using python but getting this error.
`arrays must all be same length`

I managed to get 2-D plot.

[image: Attached]

I had used the another method to check if the netcdf file is okay(convert to [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p5FP4Or0GBnunFof_Brl9mlfCPqfXC6g)). I had plotted using plotly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('bathy_bedford.csv')
z = z_data.values
sh_0, sh_1 = z.shape
x, y = np.linspace(44.66875, 44.74791667, sh_0), np.linspace(-63.69791667, -63.52708333, sh_1)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                                  highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))
fig.update_layout(title='Bedford Basin Elevation',xaxis_title="Latitude", 
                  yaxis_title="Longitude",autosize=False,
                  width=900, height=900, 
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='Latitude',
                    yaxis_title='Longitude',
                    zaxis_title='Elevation'),
                    margin=dict(r=20, b=10, l=10, t=10))  
# fig.update_layout(color='Elevation')
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    title="Elevation",
    thicknessmode="pixels", thickness=50,
    lenmode="pixels", len=200,
    yanchor="top", y=1,
    ticks="outside", ticksuffix="",
    dtick=5
))
fig.show()
```

Here is the output image:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your Seaborn code? The plotly code seems to work fine

Comment: @JoshFriedlander : plotly code works fine but not able to get any points or axis on my figure, do you know what is wrong ? Then i used other method for plotting.(I had updated original post)

Comment: Did you answer your own question in your question?

Comment: Hello! I don't get the 'sh_0, sh_1 = z.shape' passage? What are you supposed to do with this line of code? Thanks